# Check if renewable subscription is active with Xamarin.Forms (Plugin.InAppBilling)

Tags: xamarin.forms, in-app-billing, subscription, in-app-subscription, auto-renewing

I have a Xamarin.Forms application with a few renewable subscriptions. I am using the [InAppBilling plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin) to purchase these subscriptions. Now my questions is: (which I already asked in [this post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/184453/check-if-renewable-subscription-is-active-plugin-inappbilling)) How can I check if the renewable subscription is active? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Through the [document](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/PurchaseSubscription.html), you can check the status by

`var connected = await billing.ConnectAsync(ItemType.Subscription);`:

Here is the example:

```
public async Task<bool> PurchaseItem(string productId, string payload)
{
    var billing = CrossInAppBilling.Current;
    try
    {
        var connected = await billing.ConnectAsync(ItemType.InAppPurchase);
        if (!connected)
        {
            //we are offline or can't connect, don't try to purchase
            return false;
        }

        //check purchases
        var purchase = await billing.PurchaseAsync(productId, ItemType.InAppPurchase, payload);

        //possibility that a null came through.
        if(purchase == null)
        {
            //did not purchase
        }
        else if(purchase.State == PurchaseState.Purchased)
        {
            //purchased!
            
        }
    }
    catch (InAppBillingPurchaseException purchaseEx)
    {
        //Billing Exception handle this based on the type
        Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + purchaseEx);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Something else has gone wrong, log it
        Debug.WriteLine("Issue connecting: " + ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        await billing.DisconnectAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate this. So my problem is, I don’t know how to check if a user already subscribed a renewable subscription or not. I tried it with this: var purchases = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.GetPurchasesAsync(ItemType.Subscription); but this returns any purchase, also if it’s expired.

Comment: I don't use this plugin before and I assume if a user does not subscribe a renewable subscription, you will get null when you call PurchaseAsync. And does illing.ConnectAsync work to check the subscription?

Comment: If I purchase the subscription again, it will return null, but every time the app checks for the subscription, this message will be shown: `you have already subscribed to this article`. And `billing.ConnectAsync` connects the device to the billing service.

Comment: Well, you can open an issue in Github of this plugin to get more help.

Comment: Yes, If you find any solution, you can share it here.

Comment: Hi, any solutions? Did you manage to solve this? Thanks